# Encryption in S3 Upload

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-s3

In given code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCred = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCred);
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(s3Client);
Upload upload = tm.upload( bucket,key,new File(file));
```

How can we add KMS SSEAlgorithm and encryption Key while uploading to s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code sample, I see you are using multi-part upload.  Start the multi-part upload using [`AmazonS3#initiateMultipartUploadRequest(InitiateMultipartUploadRequest)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#initiateMultipartUpload-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest-).  When you create the [`InitiateMultipartUploadRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/InitiateMultipartUploadRequest.html) object, you can set various encryption options such as [`setSSEAwsKeyManagementParams`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/InitiateMultipartUploadRequest.html#setSSEAwsKeyManagementParams-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSEAwsKeyManagementParams-) and [`setSSECustomerKey`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/InitiateMultipartUploadRequest.html#setSSECustomerKey-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSECustomerKey-).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method for the encryption for multipart upload
//Methods for encryption

```
public static void  addEncryption(InitiateMultipartUploadRequest multipartUploadRequest, String awsKmsEncryptionKey)
{
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm());
    multipartUploadRequest.withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(awsKmsEncryptionKey));
    multipartUploadRequest.setObjectMetadata(metadata);
}
```